# requirejs - usage in a non-SPA site

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working on a site which, though not enormous, has enough JavaScript to make me feel that it'd benefit from requirejs. The modular way that we break the page up (and functionality) seems to support this too.

While there's plenty of examples of using requirejs in single page applications, I can't see many examples of use on a non-SPA site.

For example, I'm using jQuery UI Tabs, which I want to be run on every page. So I'd want to run something like `$('.tabs').tabs();` Would you just put this in your `main.js/app.js` (or whatever you specify for `data-main`)?

Second question. The page is built up using HTML/CSS modules. The CMS behind the site knows which HTML/CSS modules are on the page and so I can dynamically write the requirejs config so that I know which JavaScript modules to initialise. Is this a common approach? Although I may actually include all JavaScript files, I'm keen to optimise the code in `main.js` to ensure that it's only executing code for modules that are being used on the page. Has anyone done this?

Thanks very much,

James.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes. You will see that you can put your JavaScript into modules that require other modules/parts of modules. This is called AMD (http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar). This way you do not have to require your scripts on a global base. You just let your modules require their needs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your requirement is different,

main.js should have function that will be called on the requirements(different requirement - different function)

This will ensure that only required code is running.

Or if you can define dynamic JS >> which will recreate on each new function call. by the CMS, its complex but possible. just like dynamic css called on the basis of browser type and version check.

--

Calling js file in all files

If you are using PHP or APS OR .NET ( you can use some header file or master file. for calling that "js" file once, else have to manually add the js file link to each file in case of static files, or

you may call the JS file using other JS file which us already used in all files.

Update: try this JS code to add `JS file` dynamically where required and not on each page..

```
$("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>');
```

This will add the script file dynamically on a page where called. So, add this line in the JS used or on a page under `script` tag; and give path of file required i.e. here `src="global.js"`

I hope this help, if any question, please reply :)

Comment: Hi MarkiK - it's not difficult for me to dynamically write in the correct JavaScript so I'll probably do this. It's really a question of how to split global (always executed code) from code only required for certain CMS modules. Do I just hard-code the global JS calls in to main.js or perhaps look at a more maintainable way of doing this? An example of global JS would be an Analytics module.